# libinput ignores .conf settings (18.10 - Synaptics Touchpad)

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, libinput

I recently made the switch from Windows to Kubuntu 18.10 and struggle with setting up my HP Spectre X360 Synaptics Touchpad. 
I changed the settings in /etc/X11/xorg.conf and /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf in the 40-libinput.conf to:

```
 Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
 EndSection
```

but after rebootint `xinput list-props 15` shows the parameter 'libinput Tapping Enabled' still as 0 and therefore Tapping doesn't work. If i change the behaviour using 'xinput set' temporarily it works just fine, so the touchpad appearantly supports it.

Thank you.